# Generalizing König's Lemma

Tags: reference-request, order-theory, ordinal-numbers

In some recent work, I need a strengthening of König's Lemma to "trees" of arbitrary ordinal heights.  Trees, in this context, are really just well-founded partially ordered sets.  See, for instance, [page 114](https://books.google.com/books?id=CZb-CAAAQBAJ&pg=PA114) in Jech's *Set Theory.*  One must be careful when modifying the "finite branching" hypothesis of König's Lemma in this situation, due to the existence of Aronszajn trees.  The generalization is as follows:

**Theorem**:  If $(S,<)$ is a well-founded partial order, such that for each ordinal $\beta$ the set of points of height $\beta$, denoted $S(\beta),$ is finite, then there is a branch in $S$ with the same height as $S.$

Here is my short proof of this result.

*Proof*: Let $\alpha$ be the height of $S.$  We recursively define the branch we want as follows.  If $\{s_{i}\}_{i<\delta}$ is defined to height $\delta,$ then we choose $s_{\delta}$ to be any one of the finitely many elements $t\in S(\delta)$ that majorizes these previous points, and which has the additional property that for any ordinal $j$,
$$(\ast)\,\, \text{ if }\delta<j<\alpha,\text{ then there exists some } s\in S(j) \text{ such that } t<s,$$
if such an element $t$ exists.  Otherwise we end the recursion.

Let $\beta$ be the height of the branch we just defined.  Suppose, by way of contradiction, that $\beta<\alpha.$  Then, from the fact that the height of $S$ is $\alpha,$ at least one of the finitely many elements $t\in S(\beta)$ satisfies $(\ast)$ with $\delta=\beta.$  Let $t_0$ be any one of them.  Since our recursion ended at $\beta$, we know that $t_0$ does not majorize our branch.  Let $\beta_0$ be the smallest index such that $s_{\beta_0}\not< t_0.$

Among the finitely many elements $t\in S(\beta)$ which do majorize $s_{\beta_0},$ there is at least one which satisfies $(\ast),$ since $s_{\beta_0}$ itself satisfies $(\ast).$  Let $t_1$ be any such element.  Let $\beta_1$ be the smallest index such that $t_1$ doesn't majorize $s_{\beta_1}.$  Clearly $\beta_1>\beta_0.$

Repeating this process, we get an infinite list of elements $t_0,t_1,\ldots\in S(\beta),$ which are distinct since the corresponding $\beta_0,\beta_1,\ldots$ are distinct.  This contradicts the finiteness of $S(\beta).$$\boxed{}$

My main question is whether or not there is a good reference for this result in the literature.  While searching the internet, I found a different proof for it at [this blog](https://strangenewuniverse.wordpress.com/2011/10/29/infinite-trees-and-konigs-lemma/).  The idea there is to pass to a slightly simpler structure.

Along those lines, if we replace $S$ with the set of points $S^{\ast}$ which satisfy $(\ast)$, then $(S^{\ast},<)$ is a wpo (that is, a well-founded partially ordered set with no infinite antichains) that has the same height as $S$.  So it also suffices to prove this theorem for wpo's.

Comment: You probably want to take a look at this: http://blog.math.toronto.edu/GraduateBlog/files/2014/03/Brodsky-thesis1.pdf and the references in there.

Comment: Another argument: 1. If there is a highest level $S(\phi)$, then for each $x\in S(\phi)$ the set $\{y:y\leq x\}$ is a branch intersecting all levels. 2. If there is no highest level, then let $U$ be an ultrafilter such that $\bigcup\{S(\beta):\beta<\alpha\}\notin U$`` for any $\alpha<\phi$, where $\phi$ is least that $S(\phi)=\emptyset$. For each level $S(\beta)$ there is a unique element $x_\beta\in S(\beta)$ such that $U(x_\beta)=\{z:z\geq x_\beta\}\in U$ and one can easily see that $B=\{x_\beta:\beta<\phi\}$ is a branch.

Comment: König the father wrote his name with ö; but Kőnig the son wrote his name with ő.

Comment: @AsafKaragila what are you talking about? It's a German word.

Comment: @MonroeEskew A German word can be a Hungarian name (or can become one by changing the shape of the accent).

Comment: @PéterKomjáth Doesn't part 2 of your proof also cover the case where there is a highest nonempty level? (The $\phi$ in 2 will be the level after the highest, the only important $\alpha$ will be the highest level, and $\beta$ will range over the levels below the highest. So $U$ will concentrate on level $\alpha$, it will therefore contain a top-level singleton $\{x\}$, and the branch you get from $U$ in case 2 will be the same as what you got from $x$ in case 1.)

Comment: @Monroe: Yes, it's a German word, for Hungarian mathematicians. Just because you're now in Vienna doesn't mean that everyone and everywhere and everything should be German.

Comment: Koenig the father also tried to disprove the continuum hypothesis, and used the first name Julius as well in publications.  The lemma was named to honor the son, who likely was involved in the discovery or invention. As far as I know, the lemma had nothing at all to do with checkers.  Gerhard "Not Doing Cut And Paste" Paseman, 2019.08.29.

Comment: @AsafKaragila There’s still only one good language.

Comment: @Monroe: Ancient Sumerian, yes.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman: I don't know what operating system you're using, but on Linux you can define a Compose key. Then `Compose+"+o` (in sequence) produces ö, and `Compose+=+o` (in sequence) produces ő. No more cutting and pasting!

Comment: I'm using a cell phone with a virtual keyboard and a demon inside it called spellcheck. It's a wonder I get as much done on this forum as I do.  Gerhard "Double Quotes Easier To Type" Paseman, 2019.08.29.

Comment: @GerhardPaseman no hold-and-select-choice-of-accent option?

Comment: Combine that with something that changes your typing right after you type it. Not to mention the occasional delays between entry and display. (I'm sure it's possible to add Di a critical marks, but see what happens after I type normally.) Gerhard "Is Using The Wrong Tool" Paseman, 2019.08.29.

Comment: I think that the proof from the book uses Rado's selection lemma or some form of it, as suggested below by Pace Nielsen. This is a special case of a conjecture of Ron Aharoni (I have to check), so Pace should publish it.

Comment: The names of Konigs: this is a strange thing. In old Hungary, quite some jews were named Konig, they used double strokes as in the name of Erdos. When they published in German (and foreign language publications were almost exclusively German those days) father and son used umlaut. Denes Konig (the son) was a teacher of Erdos. He commited suicide in October 1944 when a Nazi party (the Arrow Cross Party) took power in Hungary and murdering Jews was just very general..

Comment: Actually the result is in Aharoni, Korman: Greene-Kleitman theorem for infinite posets, Order, 9(1992), 245-253. (Sorry for having claimed that it is new.)

Answer (score 2):

I found the paper "[Generalizing König's Infinity Lemma](https://projecteuclid.org/euclid.ndjfl/1093887927)" by Robert H. Cowan.  Theorem 3 gets this result in a nice, more general form.  Cowan's theorem is equivalent, over ZF, to the ultrafilter lemma, tying nicely into Péter Komjáth's comment.

Comment: Since the "weak Kőnig's lemma" is equivalent to the compactness of the Cantor set, and in general the compactness of $2^X$ is equivalent to the compactness theorem of first-order logic which is equivalent to the ultrafilter lemma, it's not very surprising.

Comment: Various tree versions have also been used by Stevo and Saharon.

Comment: (That is, Stevo Todorcevic and Saharon Shelah.)