# Spelling König's Lemma

Tags: ho.history-overview

I was surprised to learn [here](https://strangenewuniverse.wordpress.com/2011/10/29/infinite-trees-and-konigs-lemma/) that the man responsible for "König's Lemma" was Hungarian, and spelled his last name Kőnig (with a different accent on the o), presumably with the same accent that occurs in Paul Erdős' last name.  I still remember being taught that this accent was not an umlaut, and had a special LaTeX command.

Now, in the Konig-case, what adds more to the confusion is that we mathematicians historically have used the (incorrect) umlaut spelling when referring to the the tree lemma.  Moreover, Kőnig's father apparently spelled his name with an umlaut (according to a comment by Asaf Karagila [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/338783/generalizing-k%C3%B6nigs-lemma)).

Should we as a math community correct the spelling of "König's Lemma" to match the name of the one honored by it?

---

Edited to add:  The story gets even weirder. Kőnig sometimes spelled his name (or, at least, the editors spelled his name) as König in some of his publications.  For the 1927 publication in question, the marking on his name, on the first page, is hard to make out, but appears to be the Hungarian marking.  But on the running header throughout the paper, the markings are clearly the German umlaut!

Comment: changing the spelling would be a way to distinguish that result from other results that would otherwise have the same name: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/König%27s_theorem

Comment: Your source may be correct about the spelling of the man's last name, bit it misspells his first name as "Dénis".

Comment: There is a simple rule on spelling of names that I try to observe: if a person wrote papers in a language using Latin alphabet, spell in the same way s/he did himself/herself.

Comment: I think the respectable thing is to use the version that may be commonly found, and note parenthetically the original or honorary version. That way the reader can determine whether to find it again quickly or work on changing the literature going forward to reflect the originator. Gerhard "When Rose Is Not Rose" Paseman, 2019.08.29.

Comment: This question is greatly complicated by matters of history and nationality. The name König does not come from the Hungarian language, but from German. Kőnig is a transliteration of König into Hungarian that must have been chosen for phonetic reasons (the ö and ő both exist in Hungarian with different pronunciations). Probably Julius König/Gyula Kőnig considered these names just two translations of the same name into German and Hungarian, respectively. Also, he died before WWI, so Hungary and Austria were still the same country.

Comment: Dénes Kőnig seems to have used König when publishing in French and German:
https://gallica.bnf.fr/ark:/12148/bpt6k112092/f93.image
https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/BF01215899
Unlike his father, he kept his first name the same, instead of translating it.

Comment: I don't think it's worthwhile to correct this in K\H{o}nig's case, considering how often one sees Erd\H{o}s's name written with a German umlaut.

Comment: @AlexandreEremenko I try to follow the same rule, which sometimes means that when I cite two papers by the same author, I used different versions of their name!

In the paper where Kőnig introduced the tree lemma he did use the Hungarian last name marking.

Comment: @RobertFurber Not universally.  The paper where he proves the tree lemma is in German, but uses the Hungarian markings (as far as I can tell) on his last name. (Actually, it gets even weirder, see my edit above!)

Comment: Another mathematical illustration of the point @Robert made: Lipót Fejér's ... father was Samu (or Samuel) Weiss.... The reader will have noticed that Fejér's father had the name Weiss and, indeed, Lipót Fejér was given the name Leopold Weiss when he was born. He changed his name around 1900 to make himself more Hungarian. This was standard practice carried out at that time to show solidarity with Hungarian culture. Weiss in German means "white" while the Hungarian for white is "feher" but he chose the name "Fejér" which is an archaic spelling for the Hungarian for "White".

Comment: That was quoted from http://www-history.mcs.st-and.ac.uk/Biographies/Fejer.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In [A tale of three eras: The discovery and rediscovery of the Hungarian Method](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=&ved=2ahUKEwiE36aWl_DpAhWNTsAKHbOZA6Y4KBAWMAV6BAgFEAE&url=http%3A%2F%2Fwww.math.toronto.edu%2Fmccann%2F1855%2FKuhnEJOR12.pdf&usg=AOvVaw3VvgdtGwwEQHNMUSQft7Qy) 
Harold W. Kuhn adresses the issue under point **4. Who was Dénes Konig?** and clarifies that the correct spelling is with the Hungarian "double acute" and not the German "umlaut" that appears in the German word for "king".

Comment: Somehow I missed this answer.  That letter, where Konig himself says to use the Hungarian double acute, makes it clear which to use.  Thanks!